# Can someone use the Telekinesis power with an Area modifier to attempt an Area Grapple?

Tags: grapple, area-of-effect, mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-2e

If I have the Telekinesis power with an Area modifier (also Selective and Damaging, why not?), can I attempt grappling multiple opponents in the area with it like an enraged Sith Lord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see nothing in the rules which would forbid it, although as a GM, I'd probably argue that any Area action must be applied equally, so if you've got a half dozen people grabbed, you can't make your next Standard action to be force-choking half of them and flinging the others into their compatriots. You're either doing damage, or throwing people, and you can't throw them in different directions without Autofire or Split.